# Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\xA0",...' for column 'properties' error in MySQL Events data

Tags: mysql, pentaho, collation, utf8mb4, character-set

I know there are a bunch of posts relating to this issue. But nothing worked for me.
The issue is I get this error when I insert events data into mysql table. This error specifically comes due to properties column which is of JSON type. I know this occurs due to character set. So I changed the below mentioned global variables to 'utf8mb4' from utf8.

**1.** character_set_client

**2.** character_set_results

**3.** character_set_database

Because mysql stores 3-bytes rather than 4-bytes. But after this change, error persists.
Is there anything I am missing?

Sample data of column properties is

```
{"browser":"Safari","company_id":"1234","country":"UAE","date":"20200513","datetime":"2020.05.13 at 00:03:42"}
```

**MySQL Version:** 5.6.10

**ETL Tool I am using to insert data into table:** Pentaho

Comment:  - Did you change the column's `CHARACTER SET`?  utf8mb4 _does_ store 4 bytes _if_ you can get the bytes to it.

Comment: Yes, I had already set column Character Set to utf8mb4. But no Success

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%', the connection parameters (from pentaho to MySQL), and anything else relevant.

Comment: @RickJames 
[character_set_client: utf8]------
[character_set_connection:utf8]------
[character_set_database:utf8mb4]------
[character_set_filesystem: binary]------
[character_set_results: utf8]------
[character_set_server:latin1]------
[character_set_system:utf8]------